How to convert a binary string like '0xFF' to a base64 encoded string in Java?
I am working on a data migration project, which contains binary strings from SQL Server queries, which come across in a string format '0xFF...'. I need to convert these to a base64 encoded string of the underlying binary data for the new system to read and store.
Everything I can find online seems to refer to encoding regular strings or byte arrays, but these do not seem to work for me. At the moment, I am using Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(HexString.getBytes());
But this just encodes the string to base64, I need to first convert the string to binary so I can encode that as base64.

Please provide example input and expected output.

"I need to first convert the string to binary" - So >that< should be your question.  (If you need to do A followed by B, and you already know how to do B, you can just ask how to do A.)

And probably you can do it with HexFormat - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HexFormat.html

What is HexString?

Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(HexFormat.ofDelimiter("").withPrefix("0x").parseHex(hexString)); is the one-liner. All solutions off in some way. @Bohemian is closest but you can't be constrained by what will fit in an int or long


use hexStringToByteArray to convert hex String to byte array.
use base 64 encoder , encode byte array to base 64 string
verify:

decode base 64 string to byte array.
convert byte array to hex string 2.
Compare hex string and hex string 2 to see if they are equal. If they are equal, the conversion is correct.



Main.java
import java.util.Base64;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hexString = "0x12345678";  // hexadecimal string
        System.out.println("hexString = " + hexString);
        byte[] byteArray = hexStringToByteArray(hexString);

        // Output the converted byte array
        System.out.println(">>>>output byte array");
        for (byte b : byteArray) {
            System.out.printf("0x%02X ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // encode to base64 string
        String base64Str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
        System.out.println(">>>> output base 64 string");
        System.out.println(base64Str);
        System.out.println();

        // base 64 decode to byte array
        byte[] byteArray2 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Str);

        // Output the converted byte array 2
        System.out.println(">>>> output byte array2");
        for (byte b : byteArray2) {
            System.out.printf("0x%02X ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();

        String hexString2 = byteArrayToHexString(byteArray2);
        System.out.println(">>>> hexString2 = " + hexString2);
    } //main

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {
        // Remove the "0x" prefix (if present)
        if (hexString.startsWith("0x")) {
            hexString = hexString.substring(2);
        }

        // Every two characters correspond to a byte,
        // so the length of the byte array is half the length of the string
        int len = hexString.length();
        byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];

        // Convert every two characters into a byte
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
            data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                    + Character.digit(hexString.charAt(i+1), 16));
        }

        return data;
    }

    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] byteArray) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(byteArray.length * 2);
        //Add "0x" prefix
        sb.append("0x");

        for (byte b : byteArray) {
            // Convert byte to a 2-digit hexadecimal string and append it to StringBuilder
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

} //class

output
hexString = 0x12345678
>>>>output byte array
0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 
>>>> output base 64 string
EjRWeA==

>>>> output byte array2
0x12 0x34 0x56 0x78 
>>>> hexString2 = 0x12345678


UPDATE
According to DuncG's comment ("Fortunately JDK17+ users can replace a lot of this code with methods of java.util.HexFormat"), use java.util.HexFormat
MainJDK17.java
import java.util.Base64;

public class MainJDK17 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String hexString = "0x12345678";  // hexadecimal string
        System.out.println("hexString = " + hexString);
        byte[] byteArray = hexStringToByteArray(hexString);

        // Output the converted byte array
        System.out.println(">>>> output byte array");
        for (byte b : byteArray) {
            System.out.printf("0x%02X ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();

        // encode to base64 string
        String base64Str = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(byteArray);
        System.out.println(">>>> output base 64 string");
        System.out.println(base64Str);
        System.out.println();

        // base 64 decode to byte array
        byte[] byteArray2 = Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Str);

        // Output the converted byte array 2
        System.out.println(">>>> output byte array2");
        for (byte b : byteArray2) {
            System.out.printf("0x%02X ", b);
        }
        System.out.println();

        String hexString2 = byteArrayToHexString(byteArray2);
        System.out.println(">>>> hexString2 = " + hexString2);

    } //main

    public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String hexString) {
        // Remove the "0x" prefix (if present)
        if (hexString.startsWith("0x")) {
            hexString = hexString.substring(2);
        }
        byte[] data = java.util.HexFormat.of().parseHex(hexString);
        return data;
    }

    public static String byteArrayToHexString(byte[] byteArray) {
       return "0x"+java.util.HexFormat.of().formatHex(byteArray);
    }

} //class


Fortunately JDK17+ users can replace a lot of this code with methods of java.util.HexFormat

Here is one way.  It also makes use of HexFormat as described in the answers and comments.
String hexString = "0x12345678A09BCDEF0123456787";


Using HexFormat, create the byte array of the hex string.  String.replaceFirst eliminates the prefix if it is present.
then pass the previous byte array to the encoder.

String base64 = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(
        HexFormat.of().parseHex(hexString.replaceFirst("0x", ""))));

System.out.println(base64);

prints
EjRWeKCbze8BI0Vnhw==

To reverse the process.

create a StringBuilder object, initialized to the prefix, to hold the original
then simply iterate over the decoded array and preformat the byte prior to appending to StringBuilder.

StringBuilder original = new StringBuilder("0x");
for (byte b : Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64)) {
         original.append("%02X".formatted(b&0xFF));
}
System.out.println(original);

prints
0x12345678A09BCDEF0123456787

Notes

HexFormat complains if the String to be formatted is not of even length.
It's important to use "02X" to format the bytes.  Otherwise, if the high order "nibble" is 0, it won't display it.  E.g "0A" will print as " A"
if you want lower case hex then use "02x")


String.replaceFirst eliminates the prefix if it is present. It has to be said that the notation in your example is not normal, hence the need to even do something that's outside the functionality of HexFormat's API. It's usually no prefix, or prefix before all bytes

@g00se  I'm not certain what mean.  All it does is remove the 0x from the original string if it is there. As far as I can tell, HexFormat does not do that.

To reverse it, you just need "0x" + HexFormat.ofDelimiter("").withUpperCase().formatHex(Base64.getDecoder().decode(base64Encoded));

The base64 output was a copy paste error on my part  (omitted the leading E) I corrected it.  Your solution is what I was looking for but not being that familiar with HexFormat I manufactured one.

Here's a one-liner:
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(new BigInteger(s.substring(2), 16).toByteArray());

fyi s.substring(2) trims off the leading 0x.

Close, but you can't be constrained by what will fit in an int or long . See my comment above

@g00se Fixed (and using BigInteger results in less code too).

Yes, good for Java < 17. HexFormat better for later

If the HEX value equals "0xFF", process its string as "FF". Then, use the following code to handle it. I hope this meets your expectations.
String hexString = "FF";
int decimalValue = Integer.parseInt(hexString, 16);
String binaryString = Integer.toBinaryString(decimalValue);
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(binaryString.getBytes());

